# Use processed string to refer as column name in Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

How to use refer column names using `r.sourceProcessed` and `r.targetProcessed`? The processed variables are exact same as the column name.

```
sourceProcessed = processStatusName(status: source)
targetProcessed = processStatusName(status: target)

from(bucket: bucket)
  |> range(start: startRange, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>  r._field == sourceProcessed or r._field == targetProcessed)
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.sourceProcessed != "" and r.targetProcessed != "")
  |> map(fn: (r) => {
      diffSeconds = float(v: int(v: r.targetProcessed) - int(v: r.sourceProcessed))
      time_diff = diffSeconds / 86400.0 
      return {_time: r._time, time_diff: time_diff}
    })
  |> group(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])
  |> mean(column: "time_diff")
  |> yield(name: "mean_time_diff")
```

This issue occurs only in bottom part. Following query works without throwing any errors.

```
from(bucket: bucket)
  |> range(start: startRange, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>  r._field == sourceProcessed or r._field == targetProcessed)
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

Any ideas to fix this? TIA!